# How to fix specified checkout session could not be found in Stripe payment?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, vuejs3

I am using Vue and PHP for stripe payment. But somehow stripe payment page is not loaded. I received the below error.
[image]

[image]
**PHP**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient("sk_test_5dD7CtVhKdHjRYDFm2CXnuQj7B5ceOdxpWfkixuBn5KmhIDeuSV9onck8MFGyUvZdT00eGzYl6In");
$response = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
    'success_url' => 'http://localhost:3000/sidebar/info/buy-now?success=true',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost:3000/sidebar/info/buy-now?success=false',
    'line_items' => [
        [
            'price' => 'price_1LGPHSSEBFYnfFdusJm37r2t',
            'quantity' => 1,
        ],
    ],
    'mode' => 'subscription',
]);

echo json_encode($response);
```

**VUE**

```
let sessionId = ''
// let stripe = null as any;

onMounted(async () => {
  fetchSessionId()
})

const fetchSessionId = () => {
  fetch(`http://localhost/stripe/index.php`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      sessionId = json.id
    })
}

const redirect = async () => {
  const stripe = await loadStripe(import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_API_KEY as string)
  stripe?.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: sessionId,
  })
}
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: perhaps you've used the wrong API key, or are visiting an expired checkout session. Have you made sure the session is not expired and that the API keys used to initialize Stipe.js and crate the Checkout Session are test mode keys from the same account?

Comment: @Bravo i update my question and added a screenshot of API key that i am using

Comment: So ... `sk_test_5d........` is the same as `pk_test_51.....` In what alphabet are they the same thing? - oh, so `pk_test_51.....` is the publishable one, and you've already shown the secret one in your question ... well done

Comment: @Bravo in PHP i am using the secret key and in vue i am using a publishable key. If i am not doing this then i receive another error.

Comment: yeah, I know how that works - doesn't prove that you haven't used the wrong API key, or are visiting an expired checkout session. Have you made sure the session is not expired and that the API keys used to initialize Stipe.js and crate the Checkout Session are test mode keys from the same account

Comment: I am not sure about session but other credentials are fine.

Comment: well do some debugging and come back when you're sure

Comment: This error is indicative of a API key mismatch. They key used to create the Checkout Session is from a different account to the publishable key used to initiate Stripe.js (for `redirectToCheckout`). It doesn't appear that you're using Connect, so I'd double check the API keys you're using (specifically the `env.VITE_STRIPE_API_KEY` value).